# EC2 Classic Link - Determine Classic IP Range

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

So, I am working to migrate from EC2 Classic to VPC (yeah, I know, long time in coming and this was an inherited platform).

I have created a VPC and when I go to turn on Classic Link, I get the following error:

```
The CIDR range of vpc-[id_here] overlaps with the Classic IP space
```

I looked and was not able to find a way to determine which IP Range(s) Classic uses. Is there a way to find out so I can make my VPC's not stomp all over it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`10.0.0.0/8` as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/vpc-classiclink.html).

Comment: Thanks, but a little more detail would be nice:

"VPCs that are in the 10.0.0.0/16 and 10.1.0.0/16 IP address ranges can be enabled for ClassicLink only if they do not have any existing static routes in route tables in the 10.0.0.0/8 IP address range, excluding the local routes that were automatically added when the VPC was created. Similarly, if you've enabled a VPC for ClassicLink, you may not be able to add any more specific routes to your route tables within the 10.0.0.0/8 IP address range."

Answer (score 0):

As in the comment above:

> "VPCs that are in the 10.0.0.0/16 and 10.1.0.0/16 IP address ranges can be enabled for ClassicLink